# QT C++ How to append special time to QTime?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to add time to x axis with QT C++ QCustomPlot. Current I can add the time but not a custom time value. How can I add?

```
Parser::Parser(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

    parserClock = new QTime;

    parserClock->start();
   
}

void Parser::parse(bool syncToSystemClock)
{
     listTimeStamp.append(parserClock->currentTime().msecsSinceStartOfDay());
//I'm getting current time but I need start with static time

}
```